# issue in setting UIViews, view.bounds.origin.y while using in layer renderInContext:

Tags: objective-c, ipad, pdf, uiview

I am trying to crop and then transform a UIView to a pdf file. The UIView is cropping correctly for x component, width and height. But it is taking the same y component,ie 0 for rendering.I want to crop the image 110 points from top. This is my code

```
UIView *tempV;
    tempV=self.view;
    CGRect fram= tempV.bounds;
    fram.origin.x=537;
    fram.origin.y=110;
    fram.size.width=404;
    fram.size.height=772;
    tempV.bounds=fram;
    NSLog(@"Mail");
    NSLog(@"%f,%f,%f,%f",tempV.bounds.origin.x,tempV.bounds.origin.y,tempV.bounds.size.width,tempV.bounds.size.height);
    NSMutableData *pdfData=[NSMutableData data];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, tempV.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [tempV.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer=[[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init] autorelease];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate=self;
    [mailComposer addAttachmentData: pdfData mimeType: @"application/pdf" fileName: @"Dudel creation.pdf"];
    [pdfData writeToFile:@"Dudel creation.pdf" atomically:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController: mailComposer animated: YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing something very wrong in your initial part of your code... I don't even want to go there, but let me break down a few things:

1) `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData` second parameter is a `CGRect`.

2) From what I've understood, you want a very specific rectangle of what's showing on your screen and although its center is completely different from your view controller's view (you're trying to change both origin and size). So, why create a dependency on your view controller's view's bounds? (remember bounds and center always go hand in hand).

3) So why not just get rid of the initial part of your code and do this:

```
CGRect fram = CGRectMake (537, 110, 404, 772); // A rectangle with no other dependency, since you want one very specific.

NSMutableData *pdfData=[NSMutableData data];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, fram, nil); // Passing the newly created rectangle as the second parameter to the function.
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
CGContextRef pdfContext= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[tempV.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer=[[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init] autorelease];
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate=self;
[mailComposer addAttachmentData: pdfData mimeType: @"application/pdf" fileName: @"Dudel creation.pdf"];
[pdfData writeToFile:@"Dudel creation.pdf" atomically:YES];
[self presentModalViewController: mailComposer animated: YES];
```

Comment: Thank you miamk, you solved my problem, all though I was rebuilding the bounds at the closing of this function so the problem you mentioned above was solved to some extend. But it was of course a bad code. The problem i was facing was that I was not able to make the rectangle start from  the point (537,110) as I thought but I got it by giving(537,-110) to the code. Thank you once again.